# Where do I find a list of commonly used features?

Tags: features

I've been searching around for some useful features.  I would assume that there are some common features that people use all the time, like an image gallery. Is there a place where people contribute these? I have searched Google and drupal.org but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the [Debut Project](http://drupal.org/project/debut) collection might be up your alley. From the project description:

> Debut is a set of baseline Drupal features available as apps and designed to work independently yet integrate seamlessly together.

Comment: I think the question actually refers to [Features](http://www.drupal.org/project/features), rather than the *Recipes* of days gone by.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that "like an image gallery feature for instance" meant they were asking about things like the erstwhile content-type-specific modules. I edited my answer to be useful for either intent of the word "features". Consider un-downvoting?

Comment: I was indeed asking about the features module

Comment: Removed unnecessary info related to my misreading of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per-se, more a useful suggestion that's too long for a comment :)

I would propose that your best option would be to create a [Github](http://www.github.com) (for example) account, start generating Features out of projects that you've been part of before, and pop them into some individual repositories.  That way you know what the Features are capable of.  Trust me, after a while you will build up a personal repository containing Features you'd never even have thought you'd need.

On another note, you should definitely take a look at [Apps](http://drupal.org/project/apps) (and the [Open App Standard](http://groups.drupal.org/open-app-standard)) to get an idea of the direction some Drupal distributions are taking:

> First there were modules, then there were Features, and now there are
>   Apps. Apps is the next generation of extensibility and
>   interoperability for Drupal. They provide a much better user
>   experience of extending your Drupal site by providing facilities to
>   download modules and all of their dependencies in one easy step.

Apps are pretty much a way of distributing Features from within a Drupal installation.

**EDIT**

I forgot to add this re: Apps.  [LevelTen Apps](http://drupal.org/project/levelten_apps).

> Provides an Apps connector to the LevelTen Apps server.

If you like the idea of Apps, then this is actually a pretty good answer to your question ;-)